# Running Libsodium on Mbed (Nucleo L476RG) - Mutex not allowed in ISR context

Tags: arm, mbed, libsodium, isr, nucleo

I'm trying to run some code that uses libsodium on an Mbed board.
While just including the library and running `sodium_init()` the following error is thrown on `mbed sterm`:

```
++ MbedOS Error Info ++
Error Status: 0x80010133 Code: 307 Module: 1
Error Message: Mutex: 0x200027EC, Not allowed in ISR context
Location: 0x80026B5
Error Value: 0x200027EC
Current Thread: main  Id: 0x20000EF0 Entry: 0x800257F StackSize: 0x1000 StackMem: 0x200017B8 SP: 0x100004C8 
For more info, visit: https://mbed.com/s/error?error=0x80010133&tgt=NUCLEO_L476RG
-- MbedOS Error Info --
```

It seems that libsodium tries to use some sort of mutex which isn't allowed. Not being an expert on either libsodium or Mbed OS, what could be causing this issue?
The [libsodium docs](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation#cross-compiling) state that

> cross-compiling to ARM using the GNU tools for ARM embedded processors

is possible. However, they also note that

> using libsodium on ARM Cortex M0, M3 and M4 CPUs is not recommended if side-channels are a concern.

Is this related? Is there a way to compile libsodium which will work for Nucleo boards?

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you are running a recent version of the compiler toolchain. Looks like this is a bug [fixed in current versions](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-client/issues/303).

If that doesn't work, or if it isn't a option, you can try adding `--without-pthreads` to the compilation flags.

That CPU is a Cortex M4, so the warning regarding side-channels still apply if physical security is part of your thread model.

For that platform, [libhydrogen](https://libhydrogen.org) may be better a choice than libsodium.